# Unable to access nested value in JSON string from ajax response

Tags: json, ajax, filter, nested

I understand there's multiple questions on this but none of the answers are working for me

I return an enocoded JSON string from PHP through a .ajax response

```
$.ajax({
    url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action: 'rt_check_for_new_messages',
        uid : $uid,
        pid : $pid,
        sessionStart : $sessionStart,
        room_array :$roomArray,
        messages_array : $messagesArray,   
    },
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
```

In the console I get

```
{html: "[]", messageData: "[{"roomName":"master","msgID":1638}, {"roomName":"beta","msgID":1640}]"}
```

So now I need to access "roomName" so I can filter out matches

```
var matches = $(data).filter(function(i,n) {
    return n.messageData[].roomName === 'master';
});
console.log(matches);
```

I tried every combination I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n.messageData[].roomName === 'master';` is not valid JavaScript syntax.

I believe this is what you need to do:

```
var matches = $(JSON.parse(data.messageData)).filter(function(i,n) {
    return n.roomName === 'master';
});
```

Note that I am parsing `data.messageData` here - based on the consle output you've shown us, it looks like `messageData` is a string containing JSON, and not an array.